# INFO: task nginx:22992 blocked for more than 120 seconds

Tags: azure, nginx

I'm running an Ubuntu VM on Azure.
2 days ago my server was down. I found this inside my syslog:

```
Dec 11 06:45:28 myservice kernel: [4525694.437314] INFO: task nginx:22992 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Dec 11 06:45:28 myservice kernel: [4525694.442895]       Not tainted 3.16.0-29-generic #39-Ubuntu
Dec 11 06:45:28 myservice kernel: [4525694.447905] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Dec 11 06:45:28 myservice kernel: [4525694.453525] nginx           D ffff8801bb633840     0 22992  22990 0x00000000
Dec 11 06:45:28 myservice kernel: [4525694.453531]  ffff8801a0a7bd60 0000000000000082 ffff8801a0ebf010 0000000000013840
Dec 11 06:45:28 myservice kernel: [4525694.453534]  ffff8801a0a7bfd8 0000000000013840 ffff8801a0ebf010 ffff8801b88d8d10
Dec 11 06:45:28 myservice kernel: [4525694.453536]  ffff8801b88d8d14 ffff8801a0ebf010 00000000ffffffff ffff8801b88d8d18
Dec 11 06:45:28 myservice kernel: [4525694.453539] Call Trace:
Dec 11 06:45:28 myservice kernel: [4525694.453547]  [<ffffffff817858a9>] schedule_preempt_disabled+0x29/0x70
Dec 11 06:45:28 myservice kernel: [4525694.453551]  [<ffffffff81787e45>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0xd5/0x1f0
Dec 11 06:45:28 myservice kernel: [4525694.453562]  [<ffffffff81787f7f>] mutex_lock+0x1f/0x30
Dec 11 06:45:28 myservice kernel: [4525694.453580]  [<ffffffffc048fe90>] cifs_strict_writev+0xf0/0x250 [cifs]
Dec 11 06:45:28 myservice kernel: [4525694.453585]  [<ffffffff811e0991>] new_sync_write+0x81/0xb0
Dec 11 06:45:28 myservice kernel: [4525694.453588]  [<ffffffff811e1177>] vfs_write+0xb7/0x1f0
Dec 11 06:45:28 myservice kernel: [4525694.453592]  [<ffffffff811ffdcb>] ? set_close_on_exec+0x4b/0x60
Dec 11 06:45:28 myservice kernel: [4525694.453595]  [<ffffffff811e1d26>] SyS_write+0x46/0xb0
Dec 11 06:45:28 myservice kernel: [4525694.453598]  [<ffffffff8178a1ad>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
```

"Google" told me, it has probably sth. to do with high Disk I/O rates. But my Azure monitoring showed me very low disk read/write values in the problematic timerange. Also low CPU and low memory usage.

Another guess to this issue was a faulty hardware.
How can I check if this really was the reason - and if it was: how can I solve this problem when my VM is in the cloud? Migrate to a new VM ?!

I also have a very old nginx version which I want to update - but I don't think this is the reason for this issue, is it?

Comment: *Your server was down*....you mean your nginx server alone or your entire vm down?

Comment: I mean nginx... I could still SSH into my VM.

Comment: You can try this *Solution for hung_task_timeout_secs* https://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/09/22/linux-kernel-panic-issue-fix-hung_task_timeout_secs-blocked-120-seconds-problem/

Comment: `By default Linux uses up to 40% of the available memory for file system caching. After this mark has been reached [...]` My memory usage was never above 27%